# Getting byte[] or ByteBuffer from CameraX ImageAnalysis

Tags: android, android-camerax

Is there a way to get a byte[] or ByteBuffer from the CameraX ImageAnalysis use case? Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [CameraX test app](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/fc0539bd9588dcff0fa4f85eb6748740ca792dbf/camera/integration-tests/viewtestapp/src/main/java/androidx/camera/integration/view/TransformFragment.java#L233):

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer().remaining()];
image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer().get(bytes);
```